# Difference between passing value in function by int ** a and int & a

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Is there any difference if i pass `int **a` in any function and at same place i pass `int& a`, will both create any difference?.
Ex

```
Bool issafe(int**arr, intx, int y)

Bool issafe(int& arr, intx, int y)
```

Comment: `int** a` and `int & a` are very different.

Comment: There's a world of difference. And the posted function declaration using `int& arr ` isn't valid C either, so that tag is pointless.

Comment: `int*` and `int&` would be closer to each other, a double pointer is a very different thing. It all depends on what you’re doing. `int*` might be a pointer to the first element of an array, for example, whereas `int&` will never be an array.

Comment: Do not tag C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. C does not have C++’s “reference” feature, so `int& arr` is not standard C code, so this question is not about C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of difference between the '*' notation and '&' notation.

Let us have a look at what both mean, in a general sense and little bit of technical detail.

### Reference Operator (&)

`&x` simply means *Address of x*. It will be a an address value, often represented in hexadecimal notation.

It is often used to pass by reference in functions:
`func(int &x, char a);`
This will pass `x` by reference, but `a` by value.

### Dereference Operator (*)

`*p` means *Pointer to a memory address*.
We may assign an address to this pointer using the following format:

`int *p = x`

or

`int *p; p = &x`

Once the pointer is pointing to an address, `*p` and `x` can be used interchangeable through the rest of the program.

### Double Dereferencing

Usage of `**` occurs when we need a pointer to a pointer.

For example, if we need to make a a 2D Array, we can use the `**` notation.

One pointer points to the *first element of the first row* in the matrix, while the other pointer points to the *first row in the list of rows*.

Thus, to answer your question in a few conclusive words:
Yes, there is a big difference in `int ** a` and `int & a`, so much so that they go one level beyond being opposites like `*` and `&`.